# Flask running on a different console?

Tags: flask, pythonanywhere

I am using Flask using pythonanywhere (https://www.pythonanywhere.com) and I noticed that everytime I launch a Flask application, it runs on Python3.4 console.

Is it possible to switch the console such that the Flask application I'm building would run on different python consoles such as python 2.7?

The reason is that one of the libraries I need to import is cv2 (opencv) and python3.4 console does not seem to have it installed while python 2.7 does.

Does anyone have any idea of how to do this?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: PythonAnywhere web applications don't run inside consoles, so I'm a bit confused...?  If you're running the web app's code from the editor in order to test it, then you can specify the Python version to use using [this trick](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/SaveAndRunPythonVersion), but for the web app that's being served up, it will always use the Python version specified when you set up the web app.

Comment: Great, specifying the Python version within the script solved the problem. If I don't specify it, the wep app was using Python 3.4 by default. Thanks!

Comment: Glad that helped!  I'm still a bit confused, though -- how are you accessing the web app if you're running it from a console?

Comment: No, I'm not running it from a console. After I ran the Flask app, I clicked 'Console' tap and it shows (Under Your console) "flask_app.py (Python3.4) - kill"

Comment: Right, sorry, I meant run it *in* a console.  If you click the ">>>" button while you're editing a file, it will run the code in a console.  This does *not* connect the web app to the Internet, it just runs the code in a sandboxed environment -- which can be useful for debugging, but won't allow people to see your site.  If you want to host a website using your code, you'll need to set it up on the "Web" tab.